# Opacity on file of images for a slider CSS

Tags: html, css

Quick one! Been trying to add opacity all images on a slider but it interates through a file with all images. How would I pull this off? see code. The HTML code shows how I achieved the slider. Please help

```
    .page-title:before{
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     content:'';
     background: #222222;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #222222 0%, #000000 100%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #222222 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #222222 0%, #000000 100%);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222222', 
     endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=5 );
     z-index:0;
     }

     .page-title:after{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       content:'';
       background:url(../images/background/page-title-pattern.png) right top no- 
       repeat;opacity:0.10;
       background-color: #222222;
       z-index:1;
       }
```

```
    <div class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container"  id="rev_slider_one_wrapper" data-source="gallery">
        <div class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner" id="rev_slider_one" data-version="5.4.1">
            <ul>
```

Here is the HTML CODE. It is proving impossible to call the image file and add opacity to all of them as it iterates.

```
                <li data-transition="parallaxvertical" data-description="Slide Description" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-fsmasterspeed="1500" data-fsslotamount="7" data-fstransition="fade" data-hideafterloop="0" data-hideslideonmobile="off" data-index="rs-1690" data-masterspeed="default" data-param1="" data-param10="" data-param2="" data-param3="" data-param4="" data-param5="" data-param6="" data-param7="" data-param8="" data-param9="" data-rotate="0" data-saveperformance="off" data-slotamount="default" data-thumb="images/main-slider/3.jpg" data-title="Slide Title">
                <img alt="" class="rev-slidebg" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgparallax="10" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-no-retina="" src="images/main-slider/3.jpg">

                <div class="tp-caption" 
                data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-responsive_offset="on"
                data-type="text"
                data-height="none"
                data-width="['650','650','650','450']"
                data-whitespace="normal"
                data-hoffset="['15','15','15','15']"
                data-voffset="['-10','-10','-80','-80']"
                data-x="['left','left','left','left']"
                data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']"
                data-textalign="['top','top','top','top']"
                data-frames='[{"delay":0,"speed":1500,"frame":"0","from":"x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;","mask":"x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"auto:auto;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]'>
                    <div class="border-layer"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="tp-caption" 
                data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-responsive_offset="on"
                data-type="text"
                data-height="none"
                data-width="['650','650','650','450']"
                data-whitespace="normal"
                data-hoffset="['80','80','15','15']"
                data-voffset="['-60','-60','-80','-80']"
                data-x="['left','left','left','left']"
                data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']"
                data-textalign="['top','top','top','top']"
                data-frames='[{"delay":1000,"speed":1500,"frame":"0","from":"y:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;","mask":"x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"auto:auto;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]'>
                    <h2>FYXX <br> OIL</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="tp-caption" 
                data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-responsive_offset="on"
                data-type="text"
                data-height="none"
                data-width="['650','650','650','450']"
                data-whitespace="normal"
                data-hoffset="['80','80','15','15']"
                data-voffset="['55','55','30','30']"
                data-x="['left','left','left','left']"
                data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']"
                data-textalign="['top','top','top','top']"
                data-frames='[{"delay":1500,"speed":1500,"frame":"0","from":"y:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;","mask":"x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"auto:auto;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]'>
                    <div class="text">A One Stop Shop for industrial excellence</div>
                </div>

                <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme" 
                data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-responsive_offset="on"
                data-type="text"
                data-height="none"
                data-whitespace="normal"
                data-width="['650','650','650','450']"
                data-hoffset="['270','270','15','15']"
                data-voffset="['155','155','120','120']"
                data-x="['left','left','left','left']"
                data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']"
                data-textalign="['top','top','top','top']"
                data-frames='[{"delay":2000,"speed":2000,"frame":"0","from":"y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power4.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"auto:auto;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]'>
                    <div class="link-box">
                        <a href="about.html" class="theme-btn btn-style-two">Learn more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme" 
                data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
                data-responsive_offset="on"
                data-type="text"
                data-height="none"
                data-whitespace="normal"
                data-width="['650','650','650','450']"
                data-hoffset="['480','480','15','15']"
                data-voffset="['155','155','120','120']"
                data-x="['left','left','left','left']"
                data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']"
                data-textalign="['top','top','top','top']"
                data-frames='[{"delay":2500,"speed":2000,"frame":"0","from":"y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power4.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"auto:auto;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"}]'>
                    <div class="icons-box clearfix">
                        <span class="icon flaticon-manufacturing"></span>
                        <span class="icon flaticon-robot-1"></span>
                        <span class="icon flaticon-helmet-2"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--End Main Slider-->
```

Comment: please add more details as html...

Comment: Done added the html